# How to change default embedded string for custom structs and classes in Swift

Tags: swift

Say I have a code struct of:

```
struct Point {
  var x = 0.0
  var y = 0.0
}

var p = Point(x: 5.0, y: 3.0)
println("\(p)")
```

I will get:

```
V6<AppName>8Point (has 2 children)
```

Is there anyway to convert this into something custom? In Objective-C I believe this was covered with the `description()` method, but that isn't working here.

Comment: You were almost right. it's a `description` property, not method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can! Check out the [Apple docs on the Printable protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Printable.html).

Example code from the docs:

```
struct MyType: Printable {
    var name = "Untitled"
    var description: String {
        return "MyType: \(name)"
    }
}

let value = MyType()
println("Created a \(value)")
// prints "Created a MyType: Untitled"
```

Comment: I know that's what the docs say, but on my machine if I cut and paste the above into a playground below the "import Cocoa" line I get:

Created a V11lldb_expr_06MyType (has 1 child)

Has anyone got this to work yet?

Comment: It turns out that it's broken in PlayGrounds/REPL, but not in compiled code.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone coming to this recently (Swift 2.0), the Printable protocol has been renamed to CustomStringConvertible

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to implement the [Printable](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Printable.html) protocol. Just make your class implement the protocol and add this property:

```
var description: String { get }
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2 and upper: use CustomStringConvertible

```
extension myClass : CustomStringConvertible {
    var name: String
    
    var description: String {
        self.name
    }
}
```